# How to call a web page using a different name

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I need to type in the browser www.example.com/takethequiz and when the user clicks enter to go to www.example.com/Reports.aspx.

Thank you.

Comment: On the server-side, you can make a 301 Redirect to www.example.com/Reports.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Create .htaccess
2) Write this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
rewriterule ^takethequiz(.*)$ http://otherdomain.com/Reports.aspx$1 [r=301,nc]
```

3) Modify "otherdomanin" with your domain :)